# Если цитата завершается не авторским многоточием, а обозначающим обрыв цитаты, нужна ли точка после закрывающей кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Возьмём предложение:

> Маша села за стол и стала есть виноград, ожидая, пока Серёжа соберёт
> сумку.

Теперь часть предложения отсечём, а остальное оформим как цитату:

> Автор упоминает: "Маша села за стол и стала есть виноград..."(.)

С одной стороны, точка после кавычки не нужна по общему правилу. С другой стороны, многоточие не авторское, а "техническое", обозначающее, что предложение в цитате редуцировано.

**Нужна ли указанная точка?**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133696/discussion-on-question-by-nektoid------).

Comment: @МаркИз кстати, уважаемый Модератор, тут такая история: я удалил аккаунт, потом создал новый с той же почтой и с тем же ником. Но в чатах отображается всё равно мой старый аккаунт, причём вот и сейчас, когда туда перенесли новый разговор. Что с этим делать? https://i.imgur.com/iho7IZx.png

Comment: напишите на Мете https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/ Там вас могут увидеть разработчики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Автор упоминает: **"Маша села за стол и стала есть виноград..."***  Точка не нужна.

Я эту тему понимаю так: цитирование может делаться по образцу обычной прямой речи или по образцу косвенной речи.

В первом случае **все правила сохраняются**, то есть после многоточия точка не ставится. Это самостоятельное предложение. А если используется косвенная речь, то точка ставится (дословное высказывание не является самостоятельным).

У Розенталя примеры приведены http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163   **§ 56. Многоточие при цитатах**

2. Если цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, **не является самостоятельным предложением**, то после нее ставится точка: М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…».

Если же цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, является **самостоятельным предложением**, то после кавычек точка не ставится (как при прямой речи): В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»

Comment: Да, я знаю эти правила; меня озадачило именно то, что многоточие "техническое". К примеру, мы с вами знаем, что если предложение в кавычках заканчивается точкой, то она выносится за кавычки, однако если предложение в кавычках заканчивается на сокращение с точкой, то есть на *"техническую"* точку, то ставятся обе точки: "Я читал много фэнтези, фантастики и т. п.". По-моему, схожая ситуация, как считаете?

Comment: Наверное,  я вас не совсем понимаю. Вы не считаете ваше предложение оформлением цитаты по образу прямой речи?  А разве у Розенталя последнее предложение не редуцировано? В чем разница?

Comment: Разницы нет, пример из Розенталя совпадает, но в правилах не проговорено это чётко :) Вот я и решил лишний раз уточнить.

Comment: А мне ваш термин "техническое многоточие"  не очень ясен. Что же вы все-таки имели в виду?

Comment: Только то, что оно не есть часть цитаты. Вообще говоря, не всегда возможно понять при нынешней пунктуации, когда многоточие в конце цитаты имеется в оригинальном тексте, а когда оно "техническое", то есть обозначает, что цитата обрублена относительно оригинального предложения.

Comment: Вот точка вам и подскажет это. А если пишите сами, то у вас есть полный  оригинальный текст.

Comment: Да нет, я говорю о разнице между авторским многоточием в конце предложения и тем многоточием, которое ставится цитирующим, если предложение автора обрублено. Из оформления цитаты никак нельзя сделать однозначный вывод, авторское там многоточие в конце или цитирующего. "В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»" — вот тут вот из пунктуации неясно, процитировано ли *целиком* предложение Белинского вместе с его *авторским* многоточием в конце или здесь лишь часть предложения Белинского, обрезанная цитирующим. В обоих случаях пунктуация идентична.

Comment: (Кстати, а здесь нужна запятая перед "или"? *"В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»" — вот тут вот из пунктуации неясно, процитировано ли целиком предложение Белинского вместе с его авторским многоточием в конце или здесь лишь часть предложения Белинского, обрезанная цитирующим.*)

Comment: _Sharon: Вот точка вам и подскажет это. А если **пишите** сами, то у вас есть полный оригинальный текст._ ===  Ха-ха… Вспомнились, Sharon, Ваши насмешки в отношении оппонента, написавшего примерно год назад «пишите» в подобном предложении.

Comment: @slava1947  Мне кажется, что вы что-то путаете, я обычно не делаю подобных замечаний.  С другой стороны, я  тоже говорю, что некорректная письменная речь (например, в социальных сетях или на форумах)  закрепляется в сознании пишущих, и  тогда даже грамотные люди начинают допускать ошибки.

Comment: @Nektoid   Я вот что теперь думаю. Точка не поможет определиться, был ли сокращен оригинальный текст или его сократили при цитировании. Это всего лишь оформительский знак, зависящий от способа цитирования (прямая или косвенная речь).  Поэтому судить  об этом нужно по смыслу или же обратившись к оригиналу.